# How to add values in google map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have searched in google but i couldn't get it. I need this type where values to be in markers

[image]

I tried something but i didn't get the result

```js
var locations = [
  [33.906896, -6.263123, 20],
  [34.053993, -6.792237, 30],
  [33.994469, -6.848702, 40],
  [33.587596, -7.657156, 50],
  [33.531808, -7.674601, 8],
  [33.58824, -7.673278, 12],
  [33.542325, -7.578557, 15]

];
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.975750, 10.669184),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
    icon: 'icon.png' + locations[i][2]
    map: map
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that. A [**marker with label**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels) can only show 1 character. But you can create the marker icon on the fly in code. Here is a rough example :

```js
function createMarker(width, height, title) {
  var canvas, context, radius = 4;
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,191,255)";
  context.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(radius, 0);
  context.lineTo(width - radius, 0);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(width, 0, width, radius);
  context.lineTo(width, height - radius);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(width, height, width - radius, height);
  context.lineTo(radius, height);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(0, height, 0, height - radius);
  context.lineTo(0, radius);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, radius, 0);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
  context.font = "bold 10pt Arial"
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
  context.fillText(title, 15, 15);
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

and when you place the markers :

```js
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
    icon: createMarker(30, 20, '$' + locations[i][2].toString()),
    map: map,
  });
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cfbh9va8/**

[image]

As said this is a rough demonstration, showing the technique. I am sure there is a lot of examples drawing a canvas with arrow and so on, or perhaps you can easily do this yourself. My graphical skills are not that good :)