# Google Maps Markers with numbers

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so, i'm working on a project that uses maps a lot, and a job was passed to me,
I have to make all this google maps Markers.

[image]

And put NUMBERS MANUALLY:

[image]

I asked if its possible to put the numbers by code, they say that is not, this need to be done this way.

So, i need to know, there is a way of changing this numbers by javascript or css or anything that could automatize this process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed very possible - simply use the `label` attribute :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.43, 10.3),
  map: map,
  label: '6' //<-- 6 will be the text inside the marker
});
```

demo with different numbers -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ec2cr0jw/**

But you can only add labels with *one* character, so your range of numbers is limited to 0..9. If you want more complex text or longer numbers in the markers, you can create the markers yourself from scratch, like in the answer to this question -> **[How to add values in google map v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196669/how-to-add-values-in-google-map-v3)**

Comment: Thanks, i'll something like this